# When I scroll the UITableViewCell ,before selected images changing in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to implement this functionality.please help me.
After "unblockbtnClick" click change the image ,it's fine ,but when scroll the tableview the selected images all are changing to previous images.

Here is my code.

```
  // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {


        static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"BlockedCell";


        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if(cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib;
                nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BlockedCell" owner:self options:nil];
             cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];


        }
        [btn_tblvcAddbtn addTarget:self action:@selector(unblockbtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [btn_tblvcAddbtn setTag:indexPath.row];
            return cell;
    }

    -(IBAction)unblockbtnClick:(UIButton *)sender{

        NSLog(@"Value of selected button = %ld",(long)[sender tag]);
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"remove.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

Comment: ok,Can you provide the code for this.

Comment: when you are scrolling then redrawing each cells you created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)unblockbtnClick:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cellll;
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] intValue]<6)
        cellll=(UITableViewCell *)[btn superview];
    else
        cellll=(UITableViewCell *)[[btn superview]superview];



    NSIndexPath *aaa=[tblOption indexPathForCell:cellll];


    if([ArrSelectedData containsObject:[TblDataArrr objectAtIndex:aaa.row]])
    {
//tblDataArr is table dataArray  && ArrSelectedData is a array which contain selected itme of table 

        [ArrSelectedData removeObject:[TblDataArrr objectAtIndex:aaa.row]];
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
      [ArrSelectedData addObject:[TblDataArrr objectAtIndex:aaa.row]];
        [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}
```

and this in  `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
{
 if([ArrSelectedData containsObject:[TblDataArrr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
          [tempBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tick_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    else
        [tempBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blank_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Comment: I put this code,which you given above.This is not working.Can you give another answer for this.

Comment: button images changing but not save, after scrolling.

Comment: you use ArrSelectedData array.. and don't forgot to alloc it in viewdidload method

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the nib file outside `if` condition

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        // initialize cell here
    }

   NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BlockedCell" owner:self options:nil];
   cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're scrolling a cell out of the screen and then back `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method is called. You're not setting the background there, this is why it gets reset.

To fix you need to store information about selected cell and check it in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and apply proper background accordingly.